# C++ Access violation writing location 0x000A000B

Tags: c++

I'm building this webcrawler here. This error occurs to me when I start debugging and sends me to `memcpy.asm` or `xstring` or `dbgdel.cpp` files showing me different lines of these files every time.

I was wondering if the code is wrong somehow. I started thinking I am accessing memory blocks that I shouldn't. Here is some code. I hope you can help.

The idea is to iterate through `httpContent` and get all the URLs from the `<a>` tags. I am looking for `href="` in the beginning and then for the next `"`. What is in between I am trying to put in `temp`, then pass the content of `temp` to an array of strings.

```
struct Url
{
    string host;
    string path;
};
int main(){
    struct Url website;
    string href[100];
    website.host = "crawlertest.cs.tu-varna.bg";
    website.path = "";
    string httpContent = downloadHTTP(website);


for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= httpContent.length()-7; i++){
        char c = httpContent[i];
                if(c == 'h'){
                    c = httpContent[i+1];
                    if(c == 'r'){
                        c = httpContent[i+2];
                        if(c == 'e'){
                            c = httpContent[i+3];
                            if(c == 'f'){
                                c = httpContent[i+4];
                                if(c == '='){
                                    c = httpContent[i+5];
                                    if(c == '\"'){
                    i+=6;
                    c = httpContent[i];
                    string temp = "";
                    while(c!='\"'){
                    i++;
                    c = httpContent[i];
                    temp+= c;
                }
                href[i] = temp;
                temp = "";
                cout<<href[i]<<endl;
                                    }}}}}}
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I edited the `=`, now `==`

I am also stopping the iterations 7 positions earlier so the 'if's should not be problem.

I am getting the same errors though.

Comment: Are you even serious with those `if`s

Comment: All of your if's are using `=` instead of `==`

Comment: `int i = 0; i <= httpContent.length()` Okay, well that's probably not good because `httpContent[i]` will be out of bounds on the last iteration.... `c = httpContent[i+5];`, Hmmm

Comment: @Gernot1976, I already tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Nope, I tried that too.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev That was not the answer.  I was just pointing out a problem.  If you do not change it then the code still will not work.

Comment: @AndyG I totally agree on that! Thank you! I never thought of that..... Sorry that was silly of me. I`ll try now.

Comment: You do know that there are nice little functions such as `std::string::find` which will tell you if (and where) some string is inside another? So you don't actually have to make your own compare function...

Comment: @MatsPetersson the problem is that I don't know exactly what I'm looking for between the `href="` and `"`. I went through `string.find()` , `regex` and whatnot and I figured that was the best option. Thanks though!

Comment: Shouldn't all your equality tests be == rather than =  because 
= is assignment, 
== is test for equality.

Comment: My respect, professionals, but I'm trying to figure how to make it work. I would appreciate some help after the **UPDATE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::vector< std::string > href;` to store your result.
With `string::find` you can find sequence in strings and with `string::substr` you can extract them from string.

```
#include <vetor>
#include <string>

struct Url
{
    string host;
    string path;
};
int main(){
    struct Url website;
    website.host = "crawlertest.cs.tu-varna.bg";
    website.path = "";
    std::string httpContent = downloadHTTP(website);

    std::vector< std::string > href;
    std::size_t pos = httpContent.find("href="); // serach for first "href="
    while ( pos != string::npos )
    {
        pos = httpContent.find( '"', pos+5 ); // serch for '"' at start
        if ( pos != string::npos )
        {
            std::size_t posSt = pos + 1;
            pos = httpContent.find( '"', posSt ); // search for '"' at end
            if ( pos != string::npos )
            {
                href.push_back( httpContent.substr( posSt, pos - posSt ) ); // extract ref and append to result 
                pos = httpContent.find( "href=", pos+1 ); // search for next "href="
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```